# RxJava - make a request then request every time event happens

Tags: rx-java

I found I have a common mechanic and I wonder if there is a better way to achieve it or an alternative way.

I want to make a network request when I subscribe to an Observable, and I want it to "refresh" - request again every time certain events happen, so the observable will become infinite.

for example let's say I have a request getScreenData() so when I open the screen I call it, but if there is an event such as relogin and needRefresh I want it to make the request again.

what I come up with is as follows:

```
Merge(onRelogin().map(a-> null),onNeedRefresh().map(r -> null)).switchMap(o->getData()).startWith(getData);
```

I don't like it very much as I need to map all those events to some object just so I will be able to merge them (I don't care about the values...) and I need to write getData() twice for the switch and for the startWith to get what I want.

So is there a better way to achieve this? with other operators which will get me just that. and how would you make a transformer out of this? so you will get that pattern without repeating yourself, please not we can listen to as many observables as we want to make the request again.

Edit: Observable.merge() can return Observable thus solving the need for map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up making a transformer:

```
public static class SwitchWhen<T> implements Transformer<T,T> {


    private final Observable<?>[] observables;

    public static <K> SwitchWhen<K> create(Observable<?>...observables){
        return new SwitchWhen<>(observables);
    }

    public SwitchWhen(Observable<?>[] observables) {
        this.observables = observables;

    }

    @Override
    public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> tObservable) {
        return Observable.merge(observables).switchMap(o -> tObservable).startWith(tObservable);
    }
}

public static <T> SwitchWhen<T> switchWhen(Observable<?>...observables){
    return SwitchWhen.create(observables);
}
```

you can use it like this:

```
getData().compose(switchWhen(onRelogin(),onNeedRefresh());
```

it will make a request when you subscribe to it and every time those observables in the switch when emit an item, it uses switchMap which mean it will toss the old request, it is important if it hasn't arrived yet so the recived stream will be guarantee be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `repeatWhen` operator.

```
Observable
    .fromCallable(() -> getScreenData())
    .repeatWhen(it -> it.mergeWith(whenToRepeat))
    .subscribe()
```

Where `whenToRepeat` is an observable that triggers a repeat by emmitting anything.

Further explanation of the `repeatWhen` operator [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/).

Comment: that does not solve the problem nor doing what I asked for. I'm familiar with repeatWhen,  it will allow to repeat only when I get onCompleted, that's not what I've asked for.
my original implementation will switch to a new request regardless of the getScreenData() completing, let's say you ask for getScreenData and while you are waiting you get a onNeedRefresh() event, if you use repeat you will not request it again, and it could be possible that you will get old data...

Comment: moreover, it will not compile, whenToRepeat can't be any observable

Comment: @ndori sorry about that, it was not specified in the question that you wanted concurrent execution of requests. However, it compiles fine for me.

Comment: actually switchMap will unsubscribe from the previous request, it just says, throw the old request even if it runs and start a new one.

Comment: a more important difference is that this will also work if getScreenData() is an infinite stream, as switch map will just call it again, but repeatWhen will not be called ever...